# Internal SMTP relay

Tags: iis-6, smtp

internally, our organization limits what servers and applications can send emails.  I would like to be able to have scripts that could be run on any server send an email when done.  Is it possible to install IIS SMTP on a single server and have that relay all mail the servers send to our standard relay servers?  All the advice I see on the internet talks about configuring relays for outbound connectivity, but this would be for internal use only.  the flow would be something like this, I believe

[any server] --> **My SMTP relay** --> corporate SMTP relay --> Internal Mail system

Is this doable? if so, any links on how to configure?  I have nearly zero SMTP knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doable, you should search for "SMARTHOST SMTP" in google.  If your mail server limits relaying to specific HOSTS/IP address, you'll still need to add the new server to the relay list.  Setup will be a little different depending on you mail server/version (Exchange, IIS SMTP).

SMART HOST for Exchange:
http://www.dnsexit.com/support/mailrelay/exchange/setup.htm

I have a similar setup to what you have described.  You might want want to check if your SMTP server allows relaying for authenticated users, since this might allow you current script to send emails using a domain/email user account.